# react-google-login clears the cookie/session information in my app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, react-hooks, react-google-login

I have setup authentication in my app using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login. I am unable to figure out why the session/cookie information disappears in my application when I reload the page. That is logged in users reloading the page will be logged out :(

Here is my code in my application's Login component:

```
const Login = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);

  const onSuccess = (response) => {
    axios.post(API_ONE, {
      name: response.profileObj.name,
    });

    axios.post(API_TWO, {
      email: response.profileObj.email,
    });

    navigate("/");
    setUser({
      id: response.profileObj.email,
      userLoggedIn: true,
    });
  };

  const { signIn } = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess,
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    isSignedIn: true
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={signIn}></button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I can confirm that react-google-login preserves the session information when I try to test the functionality in isolation in a simple demo application.

I spent significant time trying to figure out why this is happening but no luck yet. I would appreciate if someone could help me with any troubleshooting/debugging tips or suggest alternate ideas that I could do to achieve the authentication functionality and preserving the session on refresh.

EDIT:

1. In the simple demo app(https://github.com/Sivanesh-S/react-google-authentication) I opened the applications tab and network tab in parallel and then when I try to refresh after login, I can see the network requests to accounts.google.com. After this network requests, I can see the local storage, cookies and session information persist in the applications tab.
2. In my application when I try to refresh after login, **I cannot see the network requests to accounts.google.com**.
   The local storage, cookies and session information gets cleared in the applications tab

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/App.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.1.21",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "clear-build-cache": "rm -rf .cache/ dist/",
    "format": "prettier \"src/**/*.{js, html}\" --write",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like one of your packages clears info out. Or your code.

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: @ZhangTianYu Updated the package JSON file in the edits section. Do you have any debugging tricks to figure out what part of my code is clearing the info? I tried stepping through but I am unable to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is related to parcel. I guess parcel is doing something here.
So I recommend you to change your package.json to following.

"dev": "react-scripts start",

And please consider this line as well.

"clear-build-cache": "rm -rf .cache/ dist/",

All localstorages are saved somewhere in filesystem, but it looks like your building system clears them everytime.

Comment: I tried a bit, I guess I will have to rewrite the entire app without parcel to test this thing because its breaking all the links if I try to hack and test - do you have any other suggestions to test if parcel is reason for this issue I am seeing? I am also thinking about setting up authentication for a app in isolation with/without parcel to confirm this thing you mentioned - thanks for the idea. I will keep you posted

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: looks like parcel is not the issue, I tried setting up parcel in a simple project, installed react google login and tried refresh. It doesn't seem to clear my cookies, local and session storage. Looks like my code is doing something - any thoughts on how I can figure out why these information gets cleared?

Comment: I see... You can try this.  If you have code A, B, C, D, E, and google login.
You can remove all of them except google login, and see if it still happens

Comment: By removing code one by one, you can confirm which part causes issue, Its one of my best working debug technique when I don't have any clue

Comment: ah so I found the issue - in the onSuccess callback I am doing a redirect to homepage like this: navigate("/"); navigate is a reach-router method. When I comment this line, I see that the session/cookie information persists. So I will have to figure out how to persist the information with the state even after redirecting

Comment: By the way Is there any specific reason to navigate before setUser?

Comment: I have it so after user logs in via the Sign in using google button in the /login route in my app they are redirected to the homepage. Would you suggest rethinking my design?

Comment: I see. Just wanted to know why you didn't setUser before navigate. Any luck so far?

Comment: Even if I switch it doesnt seem to work  - I was thinking to entirely rewrite the flow so I dont have to redirect. Thanks for all your help for the troubleshooting tips. It seems definitely like my code is clearing the info...

Comment: I see... Thanks for letting me know and approve.